# How to pass anonymous functions as parameters in Rust?

Tags: function-pointers, anonymous-function, rust

I've been playing around with `Rust` the past week.  I can't seem to figure out how to pass a function that is defined as a parameter when calling the method, and haven't come across any documentation that shows them being used in that fashion.

Is it possible to define a function in the parameter list when calling a function in `Rust`?

This is what I've tried so far...

```
fn main() {

    // This works
    thing_to_do(able_to_pass);

    // Does not work
    thing_to_do(fn() {
        println!("found fn in indent position");
    });

    // Not the same type
    thing_to_do(|| {
        println!("mismatched types: expected `fn()` but found `||`")
    });
}

fn thing_to_do(execute: fn()) {
    execute();
}

fn able_to_pass() {
    println!("Hey, I worked!");
}
```

Comment: Note: you could do `fn named() { .... } thing_to_do(named);` => Rust lets you declare functions in local scopes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Rust 1.0, the syntax for closure parameters is as follows:

```
fn main() {
    thing_to_do(able_to_pass);

    thing_to_do(|| {
        println!("works!");
    });
}

fn thing_to_do<F: FnOnce()>(func: F) {
    func();
}

fn able_to_pass() {
    println!("works!");
}
```

We define a generic type constrained to one of the closure traits: [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), or [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html).

Like elsewhere in Rust, you can use a `where` clause instead:

```
fn thing_to_do<F>(func: F) 
    where F: FnOnce(),
{
    func();
}
```

---

You may also want to take [a trait object instead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html):

```
fn main() {
    thing_to_do(&able_to_pass);

    thing_to_do(&|| {
        println!("works!");
    });
}

fn thing_to_do(func: &Fn()) {
    func();
}

fn able_to_pass() {
    println!("works!");
}
```

Comment: Why ? Because functions have no environment while closures have, thus it's trivial to convert a function to a closure (add a null environment) while the reverse is much more complicated (requires a trampoline I think).

Comment: The `thing_to_do` takes ownership over `func`, meaning `func` cannot be reused in the caller. I've done some work to make it reusable using `&` but, I still haven't got how to make the `apply` function generic over any type and across the `FnOnce, Fn, FnMut` variations.